# vb 6.0 Background color in Printer object

Tags: printing, vb6

the code is writing in white on black but the black background is always printing and what should I do thanks

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

CommonDialog1.Action = 5

 Dim Txt As String
 Dim PosX As Single
 Dim PosY As Single
 Txt = "TEST TEST TEST"
 PosX = 1
 PosY = 1
 Printer.Line (PosX, PosY)-(PosX + TextWidth(Txt), PosY + TextHeight(Txt)), vbBlack, BF 
 Printer.CurrentX = PosX
 Printer.CurrentY = PosY
 Printer.ForeColor = vbWhite
 Printer.Print Txt
 
Printer.EndDoc

End Sub
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  The `Printer.Line` code is drawing a black filled rectangle and then you are drawing white text on top of that rectangle.  So it's doing exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: sorry for bad english i am using google translator black color is always printing on the printer

Comment: That is what the code instructs the printer to do.  What do you actually desire to happen?

Comment: I am sending my problem as a picture. Thank you very much for your interest. https://hizliresim.com/F68kkl

Comment: What printer are you using? Here, your code above prints "TEST TEST TEST" as white text on a black background near the top left corner of the page. The black background only prints behind the text.

Comment: 58mm pos printer zjiang ZJ-5890K